# How to properly resolve "cannot find symbol" after "Run JFlex Generator" in Intellij Language Plugin Tutorial?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

I'm going through [Custom Language Support Tutorial](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/custom-language-support-tutorial.html) and receiving compilation error on the [last section of part 4](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/lexer-and-parser-definition.html#run-the-project).

The error is: `cannot find symbol zzAtBOL = true; location: class SimpleLexer`

If I comment this line, the next error is: `cannot find symbol if (!zzEOFDone) { location: class SimpleLexer`

Commenting out both references to `zzAtBOL` and `zzEOFDone` "resolves" the issue, and I'm able to `runIde`. But obviously it's not the solution to the problem.

So, the question is how to make "Run JFlex Generator" generate valid sources in my case?

---

Some details:

Using Intellij Idea Build #IU-223.8836.41, built on March 10, 2023

Using Kotlin instead of Java for plugin implementation.

*com.example.sampleplugin.SimpleLanguage.kt*:

```kotlin
package com.example.sampleplugin

// imports

object SimpleLanguage : Language("Simple")

object SimpleFileType : LanguageFileType(SimpleLanguage) {
    override fun getName() = "Simple File"

    override fun getDescription() = "Simple language file"

    override fun getDefaultExtension() = "simple"

    override fun getIcon() =
        IconLoader.getIcon("/icons/jar-gray.png", SimpleLanguage::class.java)
}

object SimpleLexerAdapter : FlexAdapter(SimpleLexer(null))

class SimpleFile(viewProvider: FileViewProvider) : PsiFileBase(viewProvider, SimpleLanguage) {
    override fun getFileType() = SimpleFileType
}

object SimpleTokenSets {
    val identifier = TokenSet.create(SimpleTypes.KEY)
    val comments = TokenSet.create(SimpleTypes.COMMENT)
}

object SimpleParserDefinition : ParserDefinition {
    override fun createLexer(project: Project?) = SimpleLexerAdapter

    override fun createParser(project: Project?) = SimpleParser()

    override fun getFileNodeType() = IFileElementType(SimpleLanguage)

    override fun getCommentTokens() = SimpleTokenSets.comments

    override fun getStringLiteralElements(): TokenSet = TokenSet.EMPTY

    override fun createElement(node: ASTNode?): PsiElement = SimpleTypes.Factory.createElement(node)

    override fun createFile(viewProvider: FileViewProvider) = SimpleFile(viewProvider)
}
```

*com/example/sampleplugin/psi.SimplePsi.kt*:

```kotlin
package com.example.sampleplugin.psi

// imports

class SimpleTokenType(debugName: String) : IElementType(debugName, SimpleLanguage)

class SimpleElementType(debugName: String) : IElementType(debugName, SimpleLanguage)
```

`.bnf` and `.flex` files I've copied from the tutorial as is (only changed packages):

```
{
  parserClass="com.example.sampleplugin.parser.SimpleParser"

  extends="com.intellij.extapi.psi.ASTWrapperPsiElement"

  psiClassPrefix="Simple"
  psiImplClassSuffix="Impl"
  psiPackage="com.example.sampleplugin.psi"
  psiImplPackage="com.example.sampleplugin.psi.impl"

  elementTypeHolderClass="com.example.sampleplugin.psi.SimpleTypes"
  elementTypeClass="com.example.sampleplugin.psi.SimpleElementType"
  tokenTypeClass="com.example.sampleplugin.psi.SimpleTokenType"
}

simpleFile ::= item_*

private item_ ::= (property|COMMENT|CRLF)

property ::= (KEY? SEPARATOR VALUE?) | KEY
```

```
package com.example.sampleplugin;

import com.intellij.lexer.FlexLexer;
import com.intellij.psi.tree.IElementType;
import com.example.sampleplugin.psi.SimpleTypes;
import com.intellij.psi.TokenType;

%%

%class SimpleLexer
%implements FlexLexer
%unicode
%function advance
%type IElementType
%eof{  return;
%eof}

CRLF=\R
WHITE_SPACE=[\ \n\t\f]
FIRST_VALUE_CHARACTER=[^ \n\f\\] | "\\"{CRLF} | "\\".
VALUE_CHARACTER=[^\n\f\\] | "\\"{CRLF} | "\\".
END_OF_LINE_COMMENT=("#"|"!")[^\r\n]*
SEPARATOR=[:=]
KEY_CHARACTER=[^:=\ \n\t\f\\] | "\\ "

%state WAITING_VALUE

%%

<YYINITIAL> {END_OF_LINE_COMMENT}                           { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return SimpleTypes.COMMENT; }

<YYINITIAL> {KEY_CHARACTER}+                                { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return SimpleTypes.KEY; }

<YYINITIAL> {SEPARATOR}                                     { yybegin(WAITING_VALUE); return SimpleTypes.SEPARATOR; }

<WAITING_VALUE> {CRLF}({CRLF}|{WHITE_SPACE})+               { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return TokenType.WHITE_SPACE; }

<WAITING_VALUE> {WHITE_SPACE}+                              { yybegin(WAITING_VALUE); return TokenType.WHITE_SPACE; }

<WAITING_VALUE> {FIRST_VALUE_CHARACTER}{VALUE_CHARACTER}*   { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return SimpleTypes.VALUE; }

({CRLF}|{WHITE_SPACE})+                                     { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return TokenType.WHITE_SPACE; }

[^]                                                         { return TokenType.BAD_CHARACTER; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the version divergence between JFlex and *idea-flex.skeleton* used by [the Grammar-Kit Intellij plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6606-grammar-kit). It seems that the plugin at the moment takes the older *jflex-1.7.0-2.jar* with a newer *idea-flex.skeleton*.

And in this newer *idea-flex.skeleton* `zzAtBOL` and `zzEOFDone` are removed (see [IC commit](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/ae79cc5d2fc8abd6718ac1446e2158521774661b)).

So, the solution for me is to [download](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-deps-jflex/releases) and use newer JFlex from the CLI:

```bash
java -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
  -jar jflex-1.9.1.jar -skel idea-flex.skeleton \
  -d src/main/gen/com/example/sampleplugin \
  src/main/kotlin/com/example/sampleplugin/Simple.flex
```

Answer (score 2):

Check to see whether this:

```
/**
  * zzAtBOL == true <=> the scanner is currently at the beginning of a line
  */
private boolean zzAtBOL = true;
```

occurs just above this:

```
/** zzAtEOF == true <=> the scanner is at the EOF */
private boolean zzAtEOF;
```

in file idea-flex.skeleton, which should be in your project home directory.

If those lines aren't in that file, then add them, and then try Run JFlex Generator again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Upvoted it since it guided me towards the solution. But can't accept it since it is not complete by itself (i.e. it doesn't answer about `zzEOFDone` and it doesn't give a reasoning why this happens at all).